# trying to create model object with form submission in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

First time with ROR and I'm trying to create a new model object from the index view on form submission.  I think I got it figured out,  but I'm getting:

```
uninitialized constant UsersController
```

In my view I have:

```
=form_for :user, :url => { :action => "new", :controller => "user" } do |f|
    = f.text_field :username, :placeholder => 'Username', :size => 30
    %br
    = f.text_field :email, :placeholder => 'E-mail', :size => 30
    %br
    = f.password_field :password, :placeholder => 'Password', :size => 30
    %br
    %br
    = f.submit_tag 'Sign Up'
```

In my controller I have:

```
def new
user_info = :params[:user]
    @user = User.create!(user_info)
    flash[:notice] = "#{@user.username} has been added!  Please fill out your profile page."
    redirect_to user_path
end
```

Can anyone see why I'm getting this?

Comment: the first issue is you should use `f.submit` with the `form_for` helper. The helpers with '_tag' at the end are for creating forms that are not tied to a model.

Comment: thank you!  You can stare at something for a long time and just not see what's in front of you, you know?

Comment: No problem, looks like you have your actions crossed up a little too though, writing an answer to help

Comment: Oh yes I noticed that!  Fixed it.  thanks.  but now I'm getting an unitialized constant issue!

Comment: Is that the full error?  can you edit to include any stack trace?  Is there a line number? If so include code around that line

Comment: That is the full error.  no trace, no line number.  I do notice that the url is just /users.  no /new

Comment: You have a `users_controller.rb` file with `class UsersController < ApplicationController` at the top where all this code is?  Check through your code and see if you're missing an `end` or something like that. Even try commenting out all but one action and then uncover each at a time.

Comment: got it!  typo in naming file.  thanks

Comment: Check your users model, should be in `user.rb` with `class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base` at the top. If you don't follow the naming conventions Rails will get confused

Comment: Yeah,  I had a typo in the name.  Fixed it.  and now it works.  Hey, what do you know about `can't convert Symbol into Integer` errors?  Tha's what I'm getting now with the current code

Comment: We're turning this question into a chat so you should probably ask about that error as a new question. This one already covers a lot of stuff :)

Comment: ok. If you are still interested:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856656/trouble-creating-a-new-model-object-in-ruby-on-rails-params-are-a-symbol

Answer (score 1):

First issue was just using `f.submit_tag` with a `form_for` helper. Other comments..

When doing forms like this in Rails you should use the `new` action to setup an empty model for the form to work on

```
def new
  @user = User.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html  # new.html.erb
    format.json  { render :json => @user }
  end
end
```

The form will then submit to the `create` action, where you read the `params` and use those to create a User object that you'll save

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:post])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html  { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully created.') }
      format.json  { render :json => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
    else
      format.html  { render :action => "new" }
      format.json  { render :json => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The `respond_to` blocks here let you check for additional file extensions, usually .json or .xml, and give you a way to format your output for each of those extensions.

For the `show` action you could have the following:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html  # show.html.erb
    format.json  { render :json => @user }
  end
end
```

and go to  /users/1  you would see the your view rendered (this is the default thus the empty line there with the comment `#show.html.erb` you don't have to do anything assuming you have a view)

and if you go to /users/1.json you'll get just the result of `@user.to_json` which is useful for talking to Rails from your Javascript

And regarding the undefined constant issue:

1. Check that your UsersController isn't missing any `end` lines
2. Check that the relevant User model and UsersController have all the correct naming conventions so as not to confuse Rails

users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
...
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
end
```