# Trouble creating a new model object in Ruby on rails - params are a symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting a weird error I don't understand.  It seem that when I try to create a new model object, something about the params is being passed are being as symbol and I can't do anything with them.

The error I'm getting is:

```
can't convert Symbol into Integer
```

The controller action is:

```
def create
user_info = :params[:user]
if !user_info.value? ""
    if user_info[:password] == user_info[:password2] and user_info[:email] == user_info[:email2]
        user_info.delete("password2")
        user_info.delete("email2")
        @user = User.create!(user_info)
        @user = User.new(user_info)

        respond_to do |format|
            if @user.save
                format.html  { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully created.') }
            else
                format.html  { render :action => "new" }
            end
        end
end
flash[:warning] = "Please try again"
redirect_to home_index_path

  end
```

I'm trying to submit attributes with "", but I get this error.  When I removed the indicated problem line `user_info = :params[:user]` and changed everything in terms of `:params[:user]`  it still threw the error and indicated the next line as the problem.

Can anyone see why?

Comment: What line (from the exception backtrace) is the error coming from?

Comment: In addition to Zippie's answer you should remove `@user = User.create!(user_info)` line if you want to use the rest of the code with `@user.save`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn

```
user_info = :params[:user]
```

to:

```
user_info = params[:user]
```